# Prove $\int\limits_0^{\infty}\left | \frac{\cos(x)}{1+x}\right |dx$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove $\int\limits_0^{\infty}\left | \frac{\cos(x)}{1+x}\right |dx$ diverges

I tried using $\left | \frac{\cos(x)}{1+x} \right | \geq \frac{\cos^2(x)}{1+x} = \frac{\cos(2x) +1}{2x+2}$ and showing the right side diverges but it got so complicated...

Tips appreciated

Comment: Integrate over your inequality. The right hand side diverges since $\int^\infty_0 \frac{\cos(2x)}{1+x} dx$ converges (by Dirichlet's test) and thus cannot 'cancel' the divergence of $\int^\infty_0 \frac 1{1+x} dx$.

Comment: Get a bound from below by replacing $|\cos x|$ with a "triangle" (say, on $[\pi/2,3\pi/2]$, $|\cos x|\ge f(x)$ where $f(x)=x-\pi/2$ on $[\pi/2,\pi]$ and $f(x)=-x+3\pi/2$ on $[\pi,3\pi/2]$, etc. and replace $1/(1+x)$ by its minimum over each of the intervals. By doing that, you get a divergent series.

Comment: 1. Split the intergal into intervals on whish $\cos(x)$ doesn't change sign. 2. Estimate the mean of $|\cos(x)|$ on each of them and estimate $\frac{1}{1+x}$ as minimum of it's interval ends values. 3. Sum up

Comment: For large $x$, $\frac{1}{1+x}≈\frac{1}{x}$. And the average of $|cos(x)| =\frac{2}{\pi}$. So, the integral can be estimated like $\sum \frac{2}{\pi}\frac{1}{m\pi}$. As $$\sum_{m=a} \frac{1}{m}$$ diverges for any $a$ then the integral also diverges.

Answer (score 4):

**HINTS:**

Write the integral as the sum
$$\begin{align}
\int_{\pi/2}^\infty \frac{\cos(x)}{1+x}\,dx&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_{(2k-1)\pi/2}^{(2k+1)\pi/2}\frac{|\cos(x)|}{1+x}\,dx\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}\frac{-\cos(x)}{1+x+k\pi}\,dx\\\\
\end{align}$$
Then, note that $\frac1{1+{(k+3/2)\pi}}\le \frac{1}{1+x+k\pi}\le \frac{1}{1+(k+1/2)\pi}$ when $x\in[\pi/2,3\pi/2]$ and that $\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}(-\cos(x))\,dx=2$.

Comment: @user11555739 Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 3):

Break it up into a sum of easier integrals:
$$
\int_0^\infty \left| \frac{\cos(x)}{x+1} \right|\mathrm dx=
\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\cos(x)}{x+1}\mathrm dx+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_{(2k+1)\frac{\pi}{2}}^{(2k+3)\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{|\cos(x)|}{x+1}\mathrm dx\\
\geq \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(4k+1)\frac{\pi}{2}+1}\int_{(4k-1)\frac{\pi}{2}}^{(4k+1)\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos(x)\mathrm dx\\
=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2}{(4k+1)\frac{\pi}{2}+1}
$$

Comment: A  (+1) From me.

Comment: Just curious … why did you change the limits to $[(4k-1)\pi/2,(4k+1)\pi/2]$.  They were good before the change.

Comment: @MarkViola thank you! I wanted to be lazy and choose only the intervals on which $\cos$ was positive as an underestimate. On these intervals we may just take the right endpoint to estimate $\frac{1}{x+1}$ from below.

Comment: You're welcome my friend.

Answer (score 1):

we have that:
$$0\le|\cos(x)|\le1$$
but we can consider that the average of this function is:
$$\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos(x)dx>0$$
and so:
$$\int_0^\infty\left|\frac{\cos(x)}{1+x}\right|dx\ge a\int_0^\infty\frac 1{1+x}dx\to\infty$$
and so it diverges

Comment: What is $a$?  This is not a legitimate argument.

Comment: It's pretty obvious to me that $a$ is some small but positive number.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity I still don't follow the argument...

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity It's obvious?  I don't believe that $a$ is intended to be a "small positive number."  Nevertheless, the development is completely devoid of rigor.

Comment: I don't disagree that there's no rigor between the relationship.  But the broad strokes of the argument seem obvious, at least to me.  Each period of $|\cos(x)|$ has some average value.  Therefore, its effect on the integral is, in its limit, is only a constant scaling.  So there's some small positive value $a$ that bounds the second integral under the first.

Comment: This is not meant to be a full answer, just a suggestion of a way you could make the argument, hence why it isnt as rigorous as it should be

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity I liked the triple negative "don't disagree that there's no rigor."

Comment: @MarkViola isn't this meant to be about maths not picking apart the english of others

Comment: @HenryLee What is the main thrust of your argument?  And who was picking apart anyone's English?

Comment: @MarkViola simplifying cosine by finding an average value over its periodic intervals then finding a value less than this to define the target integral as a greater value than a clearly divergent integral

Comment: @HenryLee I think your argument can be tightened substantively without your having to write much more.  See my post and qbert's post as examples.

Comment: Isn't the point of this to not provide complete answers but helping OP to get to the answer themselves. And honestly attacking people defending the answer of a teen is a bit sad imo @MarkViola

Comment: Yes, you are right;  the site provides support to those seeking answers.  Sometimes that requires a full answer.  Other times, only a hint is needed.  But who is "attacking" anyone?

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity parts of what you say I believe make sense, indeed that's the thrust of my argument. But, it's definitely alarming to see what looks like control of the values of the function $|\cos(x)|$ pointwise by its average. Maybe I'm missing steps in the argument, but op is refusing to make things clear. This is after all, a math site. Broad strokes arguments don't really fly (note the tag is even real analysis).

Comment: @HenryLee I don't think he was criticizing my english, he just found it amusing.  I did as well, which is why I wrote it in the first place and later upvoted his comment. :)

Comment: Please cite a reference for this 3rd inequality or prove why it is possible to replace a function by its average value when multiplied by another (in general of course it will not hold, but in special cases I guess it will hold). I can't follow this argument and see where it is valid in general.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : let F(x) = integrate( |cos(t)| )dt from 0 to x

Then use integration by parts.

Now employ the following 
If n Pi < x < (n+1) Pi , then
n < F(x) < n+1

Use similar bound for 1/(1+x)^2 .
Now take n to infinity

Comment: How does this work?

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{array}\\
\int\limits_0^{\infty}\left | \frac{\cos(x)}{1+x}\right |dx
&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^n \int\limits_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\left | \frac{\cos(x)}{1+x}\right |dx\\
&\gt\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^n \dfrac1{(k+1)\pi}\int\limits_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\left | \cos(x)\right |dx\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^n \dfrac1{(k+1)\pi}(2)\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^n \dfrac{2}{(k+1)\pi}\\
&\to \infty\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Care to explain why the transition from the first line to the second line is true? I don't understand it